# Is it possible to pass row id to error output in SSIS?

Tags: ssis

I have a flat file where rows have ids in form of guid. What I need is to redirect error output to table which will have error row id, error column and error code. The problem is that I can map only "Flat File Source Error Output Column" which is some sort of other columns concatenation. Is there a way I can get the ID column value of the error row? The best solution I could find is to add counter which will give the row number, but that's not exactly what I need, as ids are strings in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. You get 3<sup>*</sup> columns from the Flat File Source Component's: Flat File Source Error Output Column, ErrorCode, ErrorColumn.

A Source component defines the columns that all row buffers "downstream" of that point will contain. It is responsible for adding rows and then filling the columns in that new row buffer.

The Flat File Source component has a contract that describes how it should consume the source data - this many columns, this delimiter (or this many characters) etc.

What happens though when something overflows a length, or the data type is incompatible or not all of the delimiters are present? The design decision is to either put incomplete rows into the pipeline (but then how do you determine which columns get populated - fill left to right? what about type mismatch?) or treat it as an error. Normally, this blows up the data flow but if you add an Error output path, then you can see what row failed.
And the row is the atomic unit the flat file is using as input.

```
Read line -> Parse -> Write to Output [or Error] buffer {loop}
```

You could then use a Script Task to try and parse out the GUID from "Flat File Source Error Output Column" but then you have to hope that the value is in the row. It could be that a column has an embedded delimiter that wasn't escaped, someone transferred the file using the wrong encoding/line endings, etc.

<sup>*</sup>The Flat File Source Component does expose a property in the advanced editor, Component Properties tab for [FileNameColumnName](https://billfellows.blogspot.com/2016/05/ssis-what-is-name-of-file.html) and that too will show up in the Error output path but that is the only source component I am aware of with this behaviour.